# Automating email creation on ProtonMail using (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pyautogui

I want to create 10 emails on ProtonMail.

I already automated half of the part, using `PyAutoGui` and `Selenium` but I want to make it like a checker because sometimes usernames are taken.
Now what I wanna do is this:

- Generate Random Usernames
- Check the usernames `either by Selenium or another package(suggestions if you know any)`
- If the username is valid, a notepad will be created to save the valid usernames.

This is the concept of what I am trying to build now. I am truly sorry if I sound garbage but I legit started using Python a few days ago and it hasn't yet been a week so... I'm learning :P

I have automated the part where Selenium fills the form of ProtonMail for Sign In / Sign Up, but sometimes I get the error that the Username is already taken and I want the script to check if that error message pops up, and if it does, a "reserved code" line will be executed to fix the issue. Then, the code can continue. But, I want the script not to interfere with the "reserved code" if the element doesn't pop up.

If anyone is here just to get the code ready, here you go:

```
import selenium
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Variables
protonmail = "https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en"

username = input("Please enter your desired username for the email:")
password = input("Enter your password:")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(4)
driver.get(protonmail)
time.sleep(7)

pyautogui.click(535, 501)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite(username)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]").send_keys(
    password)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]").send_keys(
    password)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(1284, 916)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(655, 762)
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: This question is asking a few too many things -- how to generate a random username, check a username with selenium, how to save valid usernames to a file. You might have better luck if you research each component of your problem individually, then narrow your issue down to one specific item you are having trouble with.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? I understand giving context to help communicate your issue here, but I don't see any description of an actual issue you are encountering. You are reaching out to a forum filled with professionals who are offering free help, and I'm trying to help you ask a better question so you are more likely to receive that completely free help.

Comment: Ok, so as I said, my main focus is to make like a "checker" script.
I have automated the part where Selenium fills the form of ProtonMail for signin up, but sometimes I get the error that the `Username is already taken` and I want the script to check if that elements pops up and if it does, a "reserved code" line will be executed to fix the issue and than the code can continue.
But, I want the script not to interfere with the "reserved code" if the element doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked the ProtonMail sign up page to locate the error message you are talking about. Based on your problem description, it seems like you want to proceed differently in your code based on the presence of this error message. Your code sample is a bit hard to read, because your clicks are all on absolute coordinates, rather than actual WebElements, so I'm not entirely sure what is being clicked throughout your example. This might be a good starting point for you:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Fill in all details on form
# Click Create Account - I assume you have already done these two steps

# Check for error message -- this is in an iframe

# switch to first iframe on the page which will contain the error message
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']")[0]

# attempt to find the error message, catch the exception if it does not exist
try:
    # Handle scenario where error message exists -- username is taken
    error_message = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Username already used']")))

    # better to write a handler method, instead of stuffing code into the try block
    call_some_handler_method_here()

except TimeoutException:
    # Handle scenario where error message does NOT exist -- meaning, username is not taken
    call_some_other_handler_method_here()
```

This code will switch to the `iframe` which contains the error message for username already taken -- this is necessary for driver to locate the element. After that, induce `WebDriverWait` in a `try` / `except` block to check if the error message exists or not.

If the error message is present, you will end up inside the `try` block, where you can call a method to proceed accordingly.

If the error message is NOT present, meaning the username is not taken, you will end up in the `except` block, where you can call a different method to proceed accordingly (such as saving the attempted username to a file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request library to check if the username is valid:

```
import requests

URL = "https://mail.protonmail.com/api/users/available"
PARAMS = {"Name": "UsernameToCheck"}

# idk what these are but it seems like they are needed
HEADERS = {"x-pm-appversion": "Web_3.16.17",
          "x-pm-apiversion": "3"}

r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS, headers=HEADERS)

if int(r.json()["Code"]) == 1000:
    print("valid username")

else:
    print("invalid username")
```